# why this integral represents the average distance between two point on a unit square

Tags: real-analysis, probability, lebesgue-integral

I'm watching [this video](https://youtu.be/i4VqXRRXi68?t=195) and get confusing about the integral. 
Can anyone explain why this integral represents the average distance between two point on a unit square?

[image]

Comment: Before asking _why_ that gives the average, you should ask, _what is_ avearage. And, it will turn out that that expression is precisely what average means (in this case).

Answer (score 3):

The quadruple integral will cycle though every possible pair of $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ in the unit square.

$\sqrt {(x_2-x_1)^2 - (y_2-y_1)^2}$ will give you the distance between those points.

We add them all up and divide by the area of the unit square (which is $1$)

Comment: Why do you have to divide by the area?

Comment: This is what I got from discord but I don't understand it. 
the hypercube is my sample space, and its volume is 1 so the probability measure is just the same as the lebesgue measure w/o requiring normalization
and the expectation of a random variable is just its integral over the entire sample space with respect to the probability measure

Comment: In this case, you don't since the area is 1.  But, supposing you wanted to find the average distance betwee every point in $[0,1]\times [0,2]$ the integral would be $\frac {\int_0^1\int_0^2\int_0^1\int_0^2 \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 - (y_2-y_1)^2} \ dy_2\ dx_2\ dy_1\ dx_1}{\int_0^1\int_0^2\int_0^1\int_0^2  \ dy_2\ dx_2\ dy_1\ dx_1}$

Comment: Can you fix the latex? I can't read it and don't know how to fix? 
Btw, I mean why do you have to divide by the area in general?

Comment: why should we divide by the volume of the space?

Answer (score 0):

You integrate over all possible values of point $1$ ($x_1 , y_1$), and likewise for all possible values for point $2$.  And you calculate the Euclidean distance between those points.  This must be normalized by the area of the sample space (1).

Done!

Comment: I don't think I understand it. The square root term is the distance. Why do you integrate them? Integrate means adding them up but I don't see why